# Reading weird values from file

Tags: c, file, scanf

Okay, so I read a file with fscanf, and it reads correctly until the last element in my txt file. The txt file contains a list of 100 integers, so it is well within the max size of my buffer(250). After the last correct read integer, it decides to store a lot of zeros, until it stores some weird negative numbers and ends up. I suspect the fscanf to somehow find some garbage information in the txt.file? Can someone run the code on an arbitrary .txt file with some integers and confirm my results?

What have I done wrong?

```
int readFile(char *filename)
{
FILE * fp;
int buffer[250];
int num = 0;
int i = 0;

fp = fopen(filename, "r");

if(fp == NULL)
{
    printf("could not open file\n");
    return -1;
}

while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &num) == 1)
{
    buffer[i] = num;
    i++;
}
fclose(fp);

int arrsize = (sizeof(buffer) / sizeof(buffer[0]));

for(int i = 0; i < arrsize; i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",buffer[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: edit: perhaps the error lies in the for loop?

Comment: `buffer` is not initialsed and you print the whole array. Print up to the `[i-1]` element.

Comment: `arrsize` is 250, no matter how many values you have read. The actual number of vaues is `i` at the time where you close the file. (You should also take care to to overflow the buffer when the file has more than 250 numbers.)

Comment: Thnx guys, I love you. I would so love having a .length function in c...

Comment: [You're not the only one.](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/cs-biggest-mistake/228701625)